# How can we completely replace the contents of a table with another table in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server

How can we completely replace the contents of a table with another table in a SQL Server database?

Like Truncate. We want to take all the data in one and put the data in the other one into it. How can we do? How do we do it with a script? By doing this automatically.

It happens in Oracle, does it happen in SQL Server? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working? What platform are you using (Ms Sql or Oracle?)? Is this a one time thing or are you trying to do this repeatedly? Are there constraints on the data? What is the actual business problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Why not just rename them?

Answer (score 2):

Just make simple insert into statement like this :
Also you can create procedure that will makes like just my simple example

```
DECLARE @employee1  TABLE(
            Emp  VARCHAR(100),
            DOB datetime
    )
    
    INSERT INTO @employee1 SELECT 'ABC','1991-03-01'
    INSERT INTO @employee1 SELECT 'XYZ','1992-12-01'
    INSERT INTO @employee1 SELECT 'AJM','1992-08-20'
    INSERT INTO @employee1 SELECT 'RNM','1991-07-10'




DECLARE @employee2  TABLE(
            Emp  VARCHAR(100),
            DOB datetime
    )
    


    INSERT INTO @employee2
    select * from @employee1


    select  '@employee1',* from @employee1
    select  '@employee2',* from @employee2
```

[SQLFiddleDemo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02d08c30d8324842a74ca05d4d0ccdde)

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct schema is same for both tables. In this case there are many way you can achieve this automatically,

Option 1: Call Stored Procedure from any web page or window service or any api.

Option 2: Create triggers.

In both way you can use following script to copy data from one table to other:

```
Truncate table <table1>
GO
INSERT <Table1> (column1, column2)
SELECT Column1, column2 FROM <Table2>
GO
```